# Stored Procedure doesn't bring results

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, spring, stored-procedures

- My stored procedure isn't bringing results as it should
- All parameters are set OK, like my table name (that is variable according to the year/month).
- When I execute the query manually on Management Studio, the results come, but when I call the procedure on my Controller, it doesn't.
- PS: the code executed directly is with other dates, but the code executed in the IDE with the informed dates should had brought a result too, I've tried with different dates, the problem seems to be in the Stored Procedure query.

[image: CONSOLE + CODE PICTURE WITH THE VOID LIST]

[image: PICTURE OF THE QUERY WORKING ON MANAGEMENT STUDIO]

---

STORED PROCEDURE CODE:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_listarRegistrosMov]
    --PARÂMETROS
    @NomeTabela VARCHAR(20),
    @DataInicial VARCHAR(20),
    @DataFinal VARCHAR(20),
    @Cracha FLOAT
AS
BEGIN
  Declare @Comando Varchar(1000)

  Set @Comando = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @NomeTabela + ' WHERE mov_data BETWEEN ' + @DataInicial + ' AND ' + @DataFinal + ' AND mov_cracha = ' + CAST(@Cracha AS VARCHAR(20))

  Exec(@Comando)
END
GO
```

---

CONTROLLER CODE:

```
    public void consultar() {
        LocalDate dataInicio = dataInicial.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
        LocalDate dataFim = dataFinal.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
        String mesInicio = String.valueOf(dataInicio.getMonthValue());
        String mesFim = String.valueOf(dataFim.getMonthValue());
        String anoInicio = (String.valueOf(dataInicio.getYear())).substring(2,4);
        String anoFim = (String.valueOf(dataFim.getYear())).substring(2,4);
        String empresaString = String.valueOf(Math.round(funcionario.getEmpresa().getCodigo()));
        long mesesDiferencaGlob = ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(dataInicio, dataFim) + 1;

        if (dataInicio.isAfter(dataFim)) {
            Messages.addGlobalError("Informe uma data inicial posterior à data final");
            return;
        }

        if (dataInicio.getMonthValue() != dataFim.getMonthValue()) {
            if (dataInicio.getYear() == dataFim.getYear()) {
                do {
                    System.out.println(mesesDiferencaGlob);
                    String tabela = ("M00"+(String.valueOf(Math.round(funcionario.getEmpresa().getCodigo())))+anoInicio+"0"+mesInicio);
                    System.out.println(tabela);
                    DateTimeFormatter formatadorInicio = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
                    String dataInicioString = dataInicio.format(formatadorInicio);
                    String dataFimString = dataFim.format(formatadorInicio);
                    System.out.println(dataInicioString + dataFimString);
                    setRegistrosTemp(eventoEspelhoPontoRepository.findAllRegistrosByFuncionarioTableUnica(tabela, dataInicioString, dataFimString, funcionario.getCracha()));
                    for (EventoEspelhoPonto item : registrosTemp) {
                        registros.add(item);                        
                    }
                    int mesInicioInt = Integer.parseInt(mesInicio) + 1;
                    mesInicio = Integer.toString(mesInicioInt);
                    mesesDiferencaGlob--;
                } while (mesesDiferencaGlob != 0);      
            }   
        }
}
```

---

REPOSITORY CODE:

```
@Query(value = "EXECUTE usp_listarRegistrosMov :tabela, :dataInicial, :dataFinal, :cracha", nativeQuery = true)
List<EventoEspelhoPonto> findAllRegistrosByFuncionarioTableUnica(@Param("tabela") String tabela,
                                                                 @Param("dataInicial") String dataInicial,
                                                                 @Param("dataFinal") String dataFinal,
                                                                 @Param("cracha") Double cracha);
```

---

Comment: What happens if you change the repository to the same parameter names as the procedure (eg:   `NomeTabela` instead of `tabela`?

Comment: I see that you have a parameter Cracha of type FLOAT that you make an exact comparison with. You convert this float to a string value in the procedure. But the string representation can be a little tricky in at least 3 ways: Precision errors can make exact comparison unreliable. Limiting to 20 characters may not be enough. Decimal point can change between dot and comma depending on settings. Try to avoid exact comparison with a float value that has been converted to a string.

Comment: @TabAlleman it doesn't change nothing, i have another procedure that does an ALTER procedure in other repository, the names are exactly the same and it works perfectly, i'm almost 100% sure that this is something related to the SELECT method in the stored procedure, I read that it has something to do with an "output" value, not sure about it...

Comment: @Morten the Float type on the Cracha it's an database error, it should have been Integer... so all Cracha's is always .0, and this one i tested have number 25.0, converting to string = 25. The weird about it is that i have another stored procedure related to cracha's too, but it is an UPDATE stored procedure, Icreated it and it worked normally, this one SELECT makes me feel that I'm missing something, because of the other sp i've done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your stored procedure, because you're using strings for dates in a dynamic sql string, you need to add 2 single quotes around them so that the string that gets executed will enclose them in single quotes.

In other words, change this:

```
Set @Comando = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @NomeTabela + 
               ' WHERE mov_data BETWEEN ' + @DataInicial + ' AND ' + @DataFinal + ' AND mov_cracha = ' + CAST(@Cracha AS VARCHAR(20))
```

to this:

```
Set @Comando = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @NomeTabela + 
               ' WHERE mov_data BETWEEN ''' + @DataInicial + ''' AND ''' + @DataFinal + ''' AND mov_cracha = ' + CAST(@Cracha AS VARCHAR(20))
```

I don't promise that's your only problem because I don't speak java, but that is definitely a problem in your stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! In this case it would be better for me to work as DATE, DATETIME or STRING? I'm fixing the sp right now

Comment: Since you're using dynamic sql, you might as well stick to STRING parameters, because you have to convert them to strings anyway when you build the dynamic string.

Comment: Indeed, it seems to have fixed my initial problem with the quotes, thanks! But i'm getting on my front end empty lines, maybe something to do with joins? going to post a picture on EDIT 1 maybe you can help me?

Comment: I'll look, but I doubt I will be much help since I don't know java.

Comment: Well i debugged the select, and it did a right job, the do repeated two times because of two different months, and each table brought me one object, normally.. but in the table no informations has been shown up, i'm taking a look here

Comment: You might want to post a new question just to address the front end issue without all the stored procedure code cluttering it.